# is there any difference between return void and not return in a void function

Tags: c#, void, return-type

Here's the situation: I call a void function in my program, it provide a messagebox with OK and Cancel, but this function is encapsulated. I need to know what the user click on.

So is there anyway I hijack into this function to know the user choice?

Or I think when the programmer write this function, he must return a void when the user click Cancel, and didn't return anything when the user click OK. Is that possible I can differentiated these two actions - return void and not return anything?

I know it seems impossible, but that is why I come to stackoverflow asking you guys.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you insist on the signature of the function? please be specific in your exact limits, we may come to a good design

Comment: Ah, the mysteries of System.Void, an actual type :)

Answer (score 2):

A function that returns void has only one return - nothing - and so there is no difference between returning nothing or returning `void`.

If you're unable to change the existing function and all it does is display a MessageBox, I'd scrap it and start again if I were you.

What you want is something like:

```
public DialogResult GetDialogResult(string message, string caption)
{
    return MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
}
```

Call that with the message you want and a caption, and you'll get a return of either `DialogResult.OK` or `DialogResult.Cancel`

If it does more than just display the MessageBox, your only option is to check for any change that the function makes if OK is clicked, for example:

- if a record is added to a database only if OK is pressed, check for that record
- if the state of the object changes, check for that change:

  ```
  OtherObject.SetValueIfOK(2);
  if (OtherObject.GetValue() == 2)
  {
      // OK was clicked
  }
  else
  {
      // Cancel was clicked
  }
  ```

Anything else and I think you're probably out of luck.

Comment: yes, but the problem is I cannot change the existing function... and there is some other function it implements so I cannot just replace the existing function with a message box...

Comment: @QiaoMeng I've added another option at the bottom of the answer, if that doesn't help I think you're probably out of luck without asking the provider of the function to make an enhancement

Answer (score 0):

"Returning void" (you'd write `return;`) is exactly the same as returning nothing.

You want to return something like a `DialogResult`. The .NET framework uses `DialogResult.OK` and `DialogResult.Cancel` frequently for what you want to do.